# How to make my DB file encrypted?

Tags: android, sqlite, apk

I'm developing an Android application with a static database in asset folder. I'm using the SQLiteAssetHelper class to retrieve data from the database. Users can't write anything into this database.

I want to make my DB file encrypted so that no one can access and obtain data from it. How can I achieve this?

Comment: So, just to clarify, you want to write to a DB on the user's device, and then encrypt it so that the person who owns that device cannot access or see any of the data you are storing there? :P

Comment: I have a DB with static data and tables. I insert the DB file in asset folder and using SQLiteAssetHelper  I am retrieving the data. So I have to make the inserted DB file encrypted. So that if anyone reverse engineeer the apk cant able to open the file.

Comment: Friends, Is there any way to make it possible ?

Answer (score 0):

There's a library for this, I have used it in the past. It's called [SQLCipher](https://github.com/sqlcipher) and it has bindings for Android (see [here](https://github.com/sqlcipher/android-database-sqlcipher))

Just be careful on how you store your decryption key. Ideally, you wouldn't store the key in the app apk, but you would fetch it from your backend, when the user opens your app for the first time.

Comment: Couldn't a user just use something like https://www.charlesproxy.com/ and intercept the key anyways? No matter what, you are going to be directly exposing the decryption key to the same device that you intend to encrypt.

Comment: I had go through this topic and is this works for SQLiteAssetHelper class ?

Comment: Is there any anyway to encrypt (SQLCipher) Database that extends SQLiteAssetHelper ? Any Solutions ?

Comment: I have seen two issues on SQLiteAssetHelper's Github ([this](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper/issues/107) and [this](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper/issues/14))  requesting this, however they were left unanswered. SQLiteAssetHelper's is just a 3-class library. I would just copy the 3 classes and replace instances of `android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase` with `net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteDatabase. You should also submit a pull request with this feature, if you'll implement support for it anyway